# Inner nested while loop is false on second iteration

Tags: php, loops

The code below creates html table data.

Row 1 is correct and returns column1 with $row['LNAME'] and then column2 with ALL of the $row1['NAME'] results (there are four).

Row 2 and onwards echo only column1 and an empty cell in column2.

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>";
 echo $row['LNAME'];
 echo "</td>";
 echo "<td>";
 while($row1 = $sql1->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row1['NAME'] . "<br>";
    }
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 }
```

It would seem that after the inner loop has completed it evaluates as false in future iterations of the outer loop where I would like it to evaluate as true.

What should I change so that the inner loop does not evaluate as false until the outer loop does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're at the end of $sql1.  You can seek to the beginning of it again, but my preference is to separate pulling the data from the DB and the iterations, so I'd write it like this (using your code as the starting point):

```
$lname = array();
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $lname[] = $row;
}

$name = array();
while($row1 = $sql1->fetch_assoc()){
    $name[] = $row1;
}


foreach($lname as $lvalue) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $lvalue;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";

    foreach($name as $value) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }

    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the code you gave me returns the right quantities of strings and they are in the right places (cells) however the strings are all 'Array'.  I will need to find where to specify ['LNAME'] and ['NAME'], thanks again

Comment: I changed your line 
echo $lname;
to
echo $lvalue['LNAME'];
and added the array indexes to $value and it works
Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I've made the appropriate edit to my code.

Comment: Thanks, in case it helps some one else do you think it is worth adding the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use [`mysql_data_seek($rs, 0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to reset your result pointer at the first row. this is under the assumption that `mysql` is hidden behind your object. for `mysqli` use [`mysqli_data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) respectively